# Accessing Arbitrary Columns from an R Data Frame using with()

Tags: r, dataframe

Suppose that I have a data frame with a column whose name is stored in a variable. Accessing this column using the variable is easy using bracket notation:

```
df <- data.frame(A = rep(1, 10), B = rep(2, 10))
column.name <- 'B'

df[,column.name]
```

But it is not obvious how to access an arbitrary column using a call to `with()`. The naive approach

```
with(df, column.name)
```

effectively evaluates `column.name` in the caller's environment. How can I delay evaluation sufficiently that `with()` will provide the same results that brackets give?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use `get`:

```
with(df, get(column.name))
```

Answer (score 1):

You use 'with' to create a localized and temporary namespace inside which you evaluate some expression. In your code above, you haven't passed in an expression.

For instance:

```
data(iris)   # this data is in your R installation, just call 'data' and pass it in
```

Ordinarily you have to refer to variable names within a data frame like this:

```
tx = tapply(iris$sepal.len, list(iris$species), mean)
```

Unless you do this:

```
attach(iris)
```

The problem with using 'attach' is the likelihood of namespace clashes, so you've got to remember to call 'detach'

It's much cleaner to use 'with':

```
tx = with( iris, tapply(sepal.len, list(species), mean) )
```

So, the call signature (informally) is:  with( data, function() )

Comment: That's a good summary of `with()`, but I'd like to know how to force the value of `column.name` to become the desired expression.